# Example of unramified covering map of degree d

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, ramification

In my self-study of Lec.10 of [Belyi Maps and Dessins d'Enfants](https://math.mit.edu/%7Esschiavo/Courses/Belyi-Sp21/index.php), I came across the following statement

> [Right after Remark 7] Let $X$ and $Y$ be Riemann surfaces and $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ be an unramified covering map of degree $d$...

I understood that an `unramified covering map` means a covering map without branch points.
And I tried to work out some intuitive example of an `unramified covering map of degree d`;

- A map being restricted to a domain without branch points, e.g., $y = \sqrt{x}$ on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \} $.

Am I right?

Comment: Sure, if you take any covering map and remove its branched points it will be an unramified covering. But really the natural thing to ask is unramified covering map of compact Riemann surfaces. Here you can use Riemann-Hurwitz.

Comment: @daruma Thank you for your reply. Perhaps, could you give me some intuitive example of unramified map derived based on Riemann-Hurwitz?
I understood that it's stating the relation of genus and Euler Characteristic but didn't quite see how it helps us to come up w/h a concrete form of unramified covering map....

Comment: Here is an example. If you have no branched points, $\chi(S)=\deg f \chi(S')$ (i.e. $\sum (e_P-1)=0$). Take for example a genus $1$ surface, a torus. The Euler characteristic of a genus $1$ surface is $2-2g=2-2=0$. Take the multiplication by $d$ map on a complex torus $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice. This is a degree $d^2$ map which is unramified.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration! Let me take a bit time to process this example!